# Storing and indexing a varchar column in which majority of the values will be numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have two tables. This is in SQL Server 2008 R2:

dbo.Source: SourceId(int), SourceName (varchar(10))

```
SourceId|SourceName
1|Source1
2|Source2
3|Source3
```

dbo.SourceIdentifiers: Id (int), SourceId(int) foreign key Source.SourceId, SourceIdentifier varchar(30)

```
Id|SourceId|SourceIdentifier
1|1|123
2|1|456
3|2|789
4|2|789
5|2|789
6|3|ABC
```

As you can see I receive data from multiple sources, most of the sources have a number as their identifier but some of them have characters too. So my SourceIdentifier column needs to be a varchar.

The tables typically get queried based on a SourceIdentifier. And I can have as many as 100 million unique source identifiers. I want the query to be super fast. I have a couple of questions:

1. If I add an index on the SourceIdentifier column, is that a good idea? Since the column has about 75% integers stored as varchars.
2. If not, what could be the alternate approach. Create two source identifier tables, one for integer sources and one for character sources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go with option 1) ie: create Non Clustered Index on SourceIdentifer Column, make sure to make it covering index if you need to fetch SourceId from the query to avoid Key Lookup.

The problem with 2) approach would that your join would becomes complex which will affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would index the `SourceIdentifier` if that makes sense to do so.  However, if you are worried about it, you could do the following:

1. Create a user defined function that parses the string and returns
   the integer representation if possible, and otherwise NULL.
2. Add a `PERSISTED` computed column to the table
   `SourceIdentifierInteger` that is defined as that result of that
   user-defined-function of `SourceIdentifier`
3. Add a filtered index on SourceIdentifierInteger `WHERE
   SourceIdentifierInteger IS NOT NULL`.

When you query, if it is an integer value, build your `WHERE` clause on `SourceIdentifierInteger`, otherwise on the `SourceIdentifier` column

I don't know that this will buy any performance gain over just indexing the `SourceIdentifier` column, but it is an option.